# Is there a way to change the Pandas str representation to show the dtypes of columns (like R' tibble or Julia's DataFrame)?

Tags: python, pandas

Is there an easy way to change the Pandas `str` and `html` representation to show the `dtypes` of columns below the headers (like R's `tibble` or Julia's `DataFrame`)?

I looked through the documentation of `pd.set_options()` and I didn't find such an option. The only way I found would be through modifying the `__repr__` and `_repr_html_` of the `DataFrame` class, probably through a subclass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick and dirty solution would be to set a MultiIndex for the columns:

```
import pandas as pd

A = ["16-01-21 0:00",
     "16-01-21 0:05",
     "16-01-21 0:10",
     "16-01-21 0:15",
     "16-01-21 0:20",
     "16-01-21 1:20",
     "16-01-21 1:40",
     ]
B = [95.75, 90.10, 86.26, 92.72, 81.54, 4, 8]
C = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0, 0]
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": A, "B": B, "C": C})
df.A = pd.to_datetime(df.A)

cols = [(c, getattr(df, c).dtype) for c in df.columns]
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(cols, names=["name", "type"])
```

which would result in something like:

```
name                   A       B       C
type      datetime64[ns] float64 float64
0    2021-01-16 00:00:00   95.75     0.0
1    2021-01-16 00:05:00   90.10     0.0
2    2021-01-16 00:10:00   86.26     0.0
3    2021-01-16 00:15:00   92.72     0.0
4    2021-01-16 00:20:00   81.54     0.0
5    2021-01-16 01:20:00    4.00     0.0
6    2021-01-16 01:40:00    8.00     0.0
```

Comment: Thanks! That indeed works for a single DataFrame, but I'm looking for a solution that I could apply to all DataFrames existing and that I could create in the working space, something in the direction of changing pandas options.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no such functionality in Pandas as it is today. I opened a feature request on their github page and accepted your answer as you did something that works -- albeit hacky.